# How to post multiple values from a single textarea to where clause in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to submit data from a single textarea such that for example, the textarea will be filled like so,

> Nissan
>   Ford
>   Toyota

and when submitted, the query will look like this with the data submitted into the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT ve.cars, sp.engine
FROM vehicles AS ve INNER JOIN specs AS sp ON ve.id=sp.id 
WHERE ve.cars IN ('Nissan','Ford','Toyota')
GROUP BY ve.cars, sp.engine;
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: This would be easy if you just split the string. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Beware, though, that you don’t leave yourself wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements, rather than concatenating variables into your query. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: Split the string on new lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a comma delimiter in the textarea then in your php code:

```
explode(",", $_POST['name_of_textarea']);
```

But you must always assume that the user will not always give a right input. They might put a malicious code to attack your website see `sql injection` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: This isn't the only thing that must be done. This alone would allow any user to execute any SQL they wanted.